# Javascript Math.random() and conditional expressions

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random, colors, nodes

I would like to share with you my thoughts about this code:

```
for (var i = 1, max = 5; i < max; i++) {
    let random = Math.random();
    let expression = (random < 1 / (i + 1));
    if (expression){
        console.log('random is: ' + random + ' and the expression is: ' + expression + ', i is: ' +     i);
    }else{
        console.log('random was: ' + random + ' and the expression was: ' + expression + ', i was: ' + i);
    }
}
```

I was studying this example taken from GitHub: https://github.com/chuckha/ColorFlood

And I had trouble trying to know what was the meaning of the expression inside the if().

I used the JS repl: https://jscomplete.com/repl/

The context of this example is that this function would take a random index from 0 to 5, to map a random color to a Node.

Here we have a sample output from the repl:

```
"random was: 0.7118559117992413 and the expression was: false, i was: 1"
"random was: 0.478919411809795 and the expression was: false, i was: 2"
"random was: 0.4610390397998597 and the expression was: false, i was: 3"
"random was: 0.7051121468181564 and the expression was: false, i was: 4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax:

```
let expression = (random < 1 / (i + 1));
```

Means:

- `(i + 1)` first add 1 to var `i`
- Next, `1 / (i + 1)` divide 1 by the sum `(i + 1)`

  - Let say `result = 1 / (i + 1)`
- `random < result`, if the random value less than above division `result` than return true, else false.

So, something simple like:

```js
for (var i = 1, max = 5; i < max; i++) {
  let random = Math.random();
  let expression = (random < 1 / (i + 1));
  console.log(
    i,
    random.toFixed(2),      
    (1 / (i + 1)).toFixed(2), 
    expression
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I first thought that it would be evaluated random < 1 so then as random uses Math.random() which gets a number between 0 and 1, excluding the one; I thought that part of the expression would be alway true.

But in fact after putting it into the repl I discovered that the 1 / (i+1) part is done first, and then it is done all together: random / result.

I have also read:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random

Please note that in the original post I simplified the code, the original code is:

```
var randomIndexFromCollection = function randomIndexFromCollection(collection) {
  var index = 0;
  for (var i = 1, max = collection.length; i < max; i++) {
    if (Math.random() < 1 / (i + 1)) {
      index = i;
      debugger;
    }
  }
  return index;
};
```

Comment: The check is this: Is Math.random() less than 1 / (i + 1), if so, it returns true, else, it returns false. It can't be random / result because there is an equality operator in there there comparing the two sides.